# HTML inside of EJS is not rendered

Tags: html, sails.js, ejs

I have been following several tutorials and for some reason my HTML will not render inside of the EJS.

Here is an example

```
<% User.find().exec(function(err, users) { %>
<% _.each(users, function(user) { %>
 <p>Test</p>
<% }) %>
<% }) %>
```

Test will never show up on the page.
Anyone know why this is?

My plan is to render some tabular data with users.

Answer (score 2):

I think one correct way to get some users out of the database and to show them would be to fetch the data inside an action and the send the data with the render method.

**Controller**

```
module.exports = {
  showUser: function(req,res){
     User.find({}).exec(function(err, users){
       if(err) return res.negotiate(err);

       return res.view("path/to/view", users);
     });
  }
};
```

**View**

```
<tr>
<% for(var i=0; i<users.length; i++) {%>
   <td><%= users[i] %></td>
<% } %>
</tr>
```

Comment: Definitely, you're right. I looked at this question quickly before and I missed that @anthony-lockett is doing his login in view. 
Anthony - controller is place for logic, view is just for render your data for user